# Special random algorithm in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, random

I'm trying to write an algorithm for the following case:

- there're several (N) variables with a number/string (pick any type)
- there's a two dimensional array of M length:

An example of array:

```
$variations = array(
  array('1.1', '1.2', '1.3'),
  array('2.1', '2.2', '2.3'),
  array('3.1', '3.2', '3.3'),
  array('4.1', '4.2', '4.3', '4.4'),
  array('5.1', '5.2', '5.3'),
  array('6.1', '6.2', '6.3'),
  array('7.1', '7.2', '7.3'),
  ...
  array('M.1', 'M.2', 'M.3', 'M.4', 'M.5')
);
```

For each of the variable I need to get a unique combination of values from the array from each level, e.g.:

- param is 567, result is 1.2, 2.3, 3.1, 4.1, 5.2, 6.1, 7.3, ... M.4
- param is 1000, result is 1.3, 2.1, 3.3, 4.3, 5.1, 6.2, 7.1, ... M.1
- ...
- param is 567, result is 1.2, 2.3, 3.1, 4.1, 5.2, 6.1, 7.3, ... M.4

UPDATE: The result should be the same if I provide the same param value over again.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You want to pick one random item from each of the sub-arrays?

Comment: The e.g needs a bit more clarification for me.

Comment: I should work like this: for each param I provide, it should go through the $variations array and pick one item from each nested array. E.g. I provide "537" as a param, then it will take (as an example) "1.2" from 1st item, then 2.3 from 2nd, then 3.1 from 3rd and so one until final one, "M.4". It should keep the variation the same for the same value and make it different if params are not equal.

Comment: i dont see this question beeing low quality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to pick one random item from each of the sub-arrays:

```
srand($param);
foreach($variations as $values) {
    $result[] = $values[array_rand($values)];
}
// if you want a string list instead of an array
$result = implode(',', $result);
// reset the random seed
srand();
```

Comment: No exactly, the result should be the same if I provide the same param value over again. I updated my question.

Comment: Edited:  Seed the random number generator with the param.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to randomly pick from one of the arrays in the `$variations` array, you can loop through them and pick something based on the amount of values.

```php
<?php

$variations = array(
  array('1.1', '1.2', '1.3'),
  array('2.1', '2.2', '2.3'),
  array('3.1', '3.2', '3.3'),
  array('4.1', '4.2', '4.3', '4.4'),
  array('5.1', '5.2', '5.3'),
  array('6.1', '6.2', '6.3'),
  array('7.1', '7.2', '7.3'),
  array('M.1', 'M.2', 'M.3', 'M.4', 'M.5')
);

$unique = array();
foreach ($variations as $arr) {
    $unique[] = $arr[rand(0, (count($arr) - 1))];
}

print_r($unique);
```

Comment: No exactly, the result should be the same if I provide the same param value over again.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is a `pseudo random number generator` because the number depends on the initial seed.

```
srand(1001); // seeding the random number
print_r(rand()); // run it 10x, always the same result.
```

If you provide a number say X, you have `srand(D+X+1); .... srand(D+X+M);` seeds where `D=initial number`. And with each `srand()` and `rand()` output, use that to shuffle that particular array and pick a number.

*How to "do the shuffle"?* An example might to to add up all the digits (4+6+9+3+5+3+9+3+2=44) and start counting the 44th item, ( ie: 44 mod [# of item in array] )